# WPF продолжить после исчезновения элемента с экрана

Tags: c#, wpf

Я делаю приложение для составления диалогового дерева посредством составления блок-схемы. В блоке отображен текст сообщения а ниже расположены варианты ответа. При удалении варианта ответа мне нужно сместить все следующие элементы вверх, а так же сместить их линии перехода, чтобы они не висели на месте пина перед моментом удаления.

В целом структара такая: элемент `State` содержит в себе `StackPanel`, который в свою очередь содержит множество элементов `TransitionPin` (пин для исходящего соединения), так же `State` содержит один пин для входящего. Каждый `TransitionPin` может ссылаться на один элемент `Transition` (линия перехода). `Transition` уже содержит начальные координаты (X1, Y1) и конечные (X2, Y2). Так же `Transition` ссылается на подключенный объект `Node`.

Допустим, я удаляю первый `TransitionPin`, тогда все остальные смещаются вверх и мне, соответственно, нужно всем их линиям указать их новые начальные координаты. Но поскольку в момент удаления самого объекта из содержимого окна он все еще находится на экране, пересчет координат происходит по уже устаревшим данным. Выходит, мне нужно дождаться момента удаления элемента с экрана графически (когда все остальные элементы уже сдвинулись вверх) и только тогда пересчитать значения.

На всякий случай прикладываю все основные файлы. Так же если кто-нибудь придумает способ упростить эту модель, буду весьма признателен.

TransitionPin.xaml.cs

```
public partial class TransitionPin : UserControl
{
    public delegate void ActionDelegate(TransitionPin sender);

    public event ActionDelegate onremove;
    public event ActionDelegate onbeginconnect;
    public event ActionDelegate onendconnect;

    public Transition transition;

    public TransitionPin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Remove(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        onremove?.Invoke(this);
    }

    private void BeginConnect(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        onbeginconnect?.Invoke(this);
    }

    private void EndConnect(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        onendconnect?.Invoke(this);
    }

    public void UpdateTransition()
    {
        Point from = Point.Add(Pin.TransformToAncestor(MainWindow.main).Transform(new Point(10, 10)), MainWindow.offset);
        transition.X1 = from.X;
        transition.Y1 = from.Y;
    }
}
```

TransitionPin.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Conversator.TransitionPin"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Conversator"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignWidth="290">
    <Grid Cursor="Arrow">
        <Thumb x:Name="Pin" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,-17,0" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="BeginConnect" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="EndConnect" DragDelta="Drag" Style="{DynamicResource PinStyle}"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF787878" Background="#FFAAAAAA" CornerRadius="4" Padding="5">
            <Grid>
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" Height="20" Click="Remove" Cursor="Hand">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="#FFFF3232" Background="#FFFF7878">
                                <Path Fill="White" Data="M2,0 L6,4 L10,0 L12,2 L8,6 L12,10 L10,12 L 6,8 L2,12 L0,10 L4,6 L0,2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFFF6E6E"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FFFF6464"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

State.xaml.cs

```
public partial class State : Node
{
    public State()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BeginConnect(TransitionPin sender)
    {
        Transition transition = new Transition();
        Point from = sender.Pin.TransformToAncestor(MainWindow.main).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
        from = Point.Add(Point.Add(from, new Vector(10, 10)), MainWindow.offset);
        MainWindow.main.span.Children.Insert(0, transition);
        MainWindow.activeTransition = transition;
        transition.X1 = from.X;
        transition.Y1 = from.Y;
        transition.X2 = from.X;
        transition.Y2 = from.Y;
    }

    private void EndConnect(TransitionPin sender)
    {
        Point mouse = Mouse.GetPosition(MainWindow.main);
        HitTestResult hitTest = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(MainWindow.main, mouse);
        if (hitTest != null && hitTest.VisualHit.GetType() == typeof(Border) && ((Border)hitTest.VisualHit).Tag?.ToString() == "Input")
        {
            Border border = ((Border)hitTest.VisualHit);
            object control = border.TemplatedParent;
            while (!control.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(Node))) control = ((FrameworkElement)control).Parent;
            Node node = (Node)control;
            if (node != this)
            {
                if (sender.transition != null)
                {
                    MainWindow.main.span.Children.Remove(sender.transition);
                    Transitions.Remove(sender.transition);
                }
                Transition transition = MainWindow.activeTransition;
                Point to = border.TransformToAncestor(MainWindow.main).Transform(new Point(10, 10));
                transition.X2 = to.X + MainWindow.offset.X;
                transition.Y2 = to.Y + MainWindow.offset.Y;
                transition.target = (Node)control;
                ((Node)control).onreposition += transition.TargetReposition;
                Transitions.Add(transition);
                sender.transition = transition;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (MainWindow.activeTransition != null) MainWindow.main.span.Children.Remove(MainWindow.activeTransition);
        }

        MainWindow.activeTransition = null;
    }

    private void RemovePin(TransitionPin sender)
    {
        Pins.Children.Remove(sender);
        MainWindow.main.span.Children.Remove(sender.transition);
        Transitions.Remove(sender.transition);

        foreach (TransitionPin pin in Pins.Children) pin.UpdateTransition();
    }

    private void Add(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        TransitionPin pin = new TransitionPin();
        Pins.Children.Add(pin);
        pin.Margin = new Thickness(0, 5, 0, 0);
        pin.onremove += RemovePin;
        pin.onbeginconnect += BeginConnect;
        pin.onendconnect += EndConnect;
    }
}
```

State.xaml

```
<local:Node x:Class="Conversator.State"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Conversator"
             mc:Ignorable="d" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Width="310">
        <Thumb Tag="Input" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource PinStyle}" IsEnabled="False"/>
        <Border Margin="10,10,0,0" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#AAAAAA" Background="#F0F0F0" CornerRadius="4" Padding="5" Cursor="SizeAll">
            <Grid>
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel x:Name="Pins"/>
                    <Button Margin="0,5,0,0">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#FF969696" Background="#FFC8C8C8" CornerRadius="4" MouseLeftButtonDown="Add" Cursor="Hand" Padding="5">
                                    <TextBlock Text="&lt;Добавить вариант ответа>" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</local:Node>
```

Node.cs

```
public class Node : UserControl
{
    public delegate void RepositionDelegate(Vector direction);

    public event RepositionDelegate onreposition;
    public void OnReposition(Vector direction)
    {
        onreposition?.Invoke(direction);
    }

    public List<Transition> Transitions = new List<Transition>();
}
```

Transition.xaml.cs

```
public partial class Transition : UserControl
{
    public Node target;

    public double X1
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(X1Property); }
        set { SetValue(X1Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty X1Property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(X1), typeof(double), typeof(Transition), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, (obj, val) => { ((Transition)obj).Recount((double)val.NewValue, null, null, null); }));

    public double Y1
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(Y1Property); }
        set { SetValue(Y1Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Y1Property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(Y1), typeof(double), typeof(Transition), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, (obj, val) => { ((Transition)obj).Recount(null, (double)val.NewValue, null, null); }));

    public double X2
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(X2Property); }
        set { SetValue(X2Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty X2Property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(X2), typeof(double), typeof(Transition), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, (obj, val) => { ((Transition)obj).Recount(null, null, (double)val.NewValue, null); }));

    public double Y2
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(Y2Property); }
        set { SetValue(Y2Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Y2Property = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(Y2), typeof(double), typeof(Transition), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, (obj, val) => { ((Transition)obj).Recount(null, null, null, (double)val.NewValue); }));

    public void Recount(double? newX1, double? newY1, double? newX2, double? newY2)
    {
        double x1 = newX1 == null ? X1 : (double)newX1;
        double y1 = newY1 == null ? Y1 : (double)newY1;
        double x2 = newX2 == null ? X2 : (double)newX2;
        double y2 = newY2 == null ? Y2 : (double)newY2;

        Margin = new Thickness(x1, y1, 0, 0);

        double deltaX = x2 - x1;
        double deltaY = y2 - y1;

        SetValue(LengthProperty, Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(deltaX, 2) + Math.Pow(deltaY, 2)));
        SetValue(RotationProperty, Math.Atan2(deltaY, deltaX) / (2 * Math.PI) * 360);
    }

    public double Length
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(LengthProperty);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LengthProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(Length), typeof(double), typeof(Transition));

    public double Rotation
    {
        get
        {
            return (double)GetValue(RotationProperty);
        }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RotationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(Rotation), typeof(double), typeof(Transition));

    public void TargetReposition(Vector delta)
    {
        X2 = X2 + delta.X;
        Y2 = Y2 + delta.Y;
    }

    ~Transition()
    {
        if (target != null) target.onreposition -= TargetReposition;
    }

    public Transition()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Transition.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl" x:Class="Conversator.Transition"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Conversator"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" Height="2" Margin="0,-1,0,0" Width="{Binding Length, ElementName=userControl, Mode=OneWay}" Background="#FF141414">
        <Grid.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Rotation, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Transition}}}"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Grid.RenderTransform>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Transition}}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<State> states = new List<State>();
    Point pos = new Point(0, 0);
    public static Transition activeTransition = null;
    public static MainWindow main;
    public static Vector offset;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        main = this;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddState(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        State state = new State();
        states.Add(state);
        span.Children.Add(state);
        Point mouse = Point.Add(Mouse.GetPosition(this), offset);
        state.Margin = new Thickness(mouse.X - 10, mouse.Y - 10, 0, 0);
    }

    private void Scroll(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        offset = new Vector(e.HorizontalOffset, e.VerticalOffset);
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Conversator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Conversator"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Conversator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Добавить положение" Click="AddState"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollChanged="Scroll">
            <Grid x:Name="span" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Conversator.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Conversator"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}" x:Key="PinStyle">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                        <Border Tag="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Name="Border" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="2" Width="20" Height="20" Background="#FF323232" Cursor="Hand" BorderBrush="#FF141414"/>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#FF505050"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Вот что происходит при удалении первого элемента на данный момент:
[image: До удаления][image: После удаления]

Comment: Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Зачем вам пересчет? Вы хотите получить координаты элементов?

Comment: Возможно вам нужно наследоваться от панели и реализовать это в `OnVisualChildrenChanged`

Comment: У меня элементы (`TransitionPin`) расположены в `StackPanel`. К каждому элементу подведена линия (`Transition`). Когда исчезает первый, то все следующие элементы сдвигаются вверх, соответственно мне нужно узнать новую позицию каждого из них и переподвести к нему линию.

Comment: Хм, интересно. Состряпайте минимальный пример, на котором это можно посмотреть и пощупать руками. Скорее всего вашу задачу можно решить более простым способом. Вместо пересчета координат вручную переложить эту работу на фреймворк.

Comment: Коротко вряд ли получится, т.к. все элементы тесно связаны между собой. Я прикрепил 4 самых основных класса.

Comment: Да уж, это далеко не [MCVE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я сократил описание `TransitionPin` и `State`. У них остались только функции для соединяния (`BeginConnect`, `Drag`, `EndConnect`) и удаления/добавления (`RemovePin`/`Add`) пинов. У `Transition` все поля и функции важны, т.к. они напрямую влияют на отображение линии.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75973/discussion-between--nop-and-purple-dragon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @АндрейNOP. Оказалось все достаточно просто. Когда элемент исчезает с экрана, у содержащего его `StackPanel` вызывается событие `SizeChanged`. На это событие как раз и надо повесить вызов функции пересчета начальных координат для линий.